# How can I start building a process bar in Terminal macOS?

Tags: terminal

I am intreated to build a process bar by myself, not just copy and paste codes or using some one else code. I am looking for a starter project or link to learn it step by step. the goal is like this image:

[image]

If you show me an example code for such thing in answer that would be also work for me.

Comment: wouldn't `example code` be the same thing as `someone else's code`?

Comment: I think you misunderstood, or may you are working to answer an English question in wrong tag and wrong question, by the way for your information! Example code which try to teach and learn step by step, or at least some kind of explaining, Not just copy and paste some one code. Or looking for same thing as link in internet, if some one had same issue like me.

Comment: a progress bar requires overwriting same line again and again with some string in place. the carriage return character `\r` will give you a good base to start with. for more advanced cursor positions read about ansi escape sequences